# Java maps and sets in same add method

Tags: java, templates

Is it possible to use the same add method to add various types of data to either a map or set, dependant on what is passed in? for example...

```
public static <U, T> void add(T _token, U<T> set>
{
    ...
}
```

Where possibly a string or double is the _token argument and either a map, map or set or set is the set variable. I understand maps accept two values with the put method, but I'm ignoring this for the moment...

Could anyone show me how to implement this sort of template pleasEe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you can't ignore it. What would be the other value in case it is a map?

Comment: How do you insert the token in the map? `map.put(token, token)`?

Comment: I'd concatenate it into a string or something to pass it into the add method and then split it in the add method. Maybe. I haven't thought it through fully yet

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this smells like a bad design. You should think deeper about your design before deciding to use this kind of method. A map and a set are very different things and usually they're not used for the same thing. It's better to overload the method instead, for example:

```
public static <T> void add(final T token, final Map<Whatever, T> holder)
public static <T> void add(final T token, final Set<T> holder)
```

Still one solution using polymorphism and generics could be as follows:

```
public static <T> void add(final T token, final Object holder) {
    if (holder instanceof Map) {
        final Map map = (Map) holder;
        map.put(KEY, token); // Or whatever you want to do in this case
    } else if (holder instanceof Set) {
        final Set set = (Set) holder;
        set.add(token);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Holder is nor a Map neither a Set");
    }
}
```

Note that this is unchecked, that is, the `Map` could be `<String, String>` and you're passing an `Integer`.

I definitely prefer the method overloading solution.

Comment: Overloading completely slipped my mind. Much better idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sets and maps have different "add" constraints, so even though you say you want to ignore it, you'd be ignoring an essential difference between them: adding an object to a set can be done with just the object, but adding an object to a map requires an associated key.

You could utilize polymorphism and define two `add` methods, one for sets and one for maps. However, it seems fairly pointless since those collections already have such behavior defined.

Comment: That's method overloading, not polymorphism.

Comment: a.k.a Ad Hoc Polymorphism, there are many forms of polymorphism